# Can't run Georefrencer in QGIS 2.18.13

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

Nothing happens when I click the Georeferencer menu in QGIS 2.18.13. No window appears (menu Raster - Georeferencer - Georeferencer). I last used the georeferencer a couple of weeks ago, most likely before the last bug fix update.

I tried fixing the problem by renaming my .qgis2 directory, essentially resetting QGIS to "factory settings". This did not fix the problem. Nothing informative appears in log. It seems the georeferencer doesn't even to try to start.

My set-up: QGIS 2.18.13 (QGIS code revision 8cba0bb9eb) on Windows 10 64-bit, installed using the OSGeo4W installer.

Anyone else having issues with the Georeferencer in the latest QGIS 2.18 release?

Comment: A few times in the past I have thought the same thing only to discover that the georeferencer window opened behind some other window and was thus obscured.  Can you confirm that is not the case?  (I am also on Windows 10 64-bit and use the OsGeo4w installer)

Comment: Slaps forehead. I sometimes use a second monitor with my laptop, yes the georeferencer was on the 2nd monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Per [comment from @MappaGnosis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259213/cant-run-georefrencer-in-qgis-2-18-13?noredirect=1#comment409889_259213) and [response from @bbrhuft](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259213/cant-run-georefrencer-in-qgis-2-18-13?noredirect=1#comment409903_259213), the window may be obscured behind another window or perhaps on a (previously connected) second monitor.

Check behind open windows, and if you sometimes use multiple monitors you may need to re-attach one (or more) to possibly locate the window on your non-visible desktop space.